# QFileSystemModel drop items issue

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I have reimplemented `QFileSystemModel` class to add the drag and drop feature between `QTreeView` and `QListView` but it still does not work. It displays the following dialog:

[image: https://ddgobkiprc33d.cloudfront.net/8f3a20b4-83fe-46bc-be2b-7454bea9b269.gif]

**ExplorerModel.h**

```
#ifndef EXPLORERMODEL_H
#define EXPLORERMODEL_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QFileSystemModel>
#include <QMimeData>
#include <QBrush>
#include <QDebug>

class ExplorerModel : public QFileSystemModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    using QFileSystemModel::QFileSystemModel;
    Qt::DropActions supportedDragActions() const;
    Qt::DropActions supportedDropActions() const;
    QStringList mimeTypes() const;
    Qt::ItemFlags flags(const QModelIndex &index) const;
    QMimeData *mimeData(const QModelIndexList &indexes) const;
    bool dropMimeData(const QMimeData *data, Qt::DropAction action, int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parent);

private:
    bool canDropMimeData(const QMimeData *data, Qt::DropAction action, int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parent);
};

#endif // EXPLORERMODEL_H
```

**ExplorerModel.cpp:**

```
#include "explorermodel.h"

Qt::DropActions ExplorerModel::supportedDragActions() const
{
   return Qt::CopyAction | Qt::MoveAction;
}

Qt::DropActions ExplorerModel::supportedDropActions() const
{
    return Qt::CopyAction | Qt::MoveAction;
}

Qt::ItemFlags ExplorerModel::flags(const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    Qt::ItemFlags defaultFlags = QFileSystemModel::flags(index);

    if (index.isValid()) {
        return Qt::ItemIsDragEnabled | Qt::ItemIsDropEnabled | defaultFlags;
    } else {
        return Qt::ItemIsDropEnabled | defaultFlags;
    }
}

QStringList ExplorerModel::mimeTypes() const
{
    QStringList types;
    types << "application/octet-stream";
    return types;
}

QMimeData *ExplorerModel::mimeData(const QModelIndexList &indexes) const
{
    QMimeData *mimeData = new QMimeData;
    QByteArray encodedData;
    QDataStream stream(&encodedData, QIODevice::WriteOnly);

    if (indexes.first().isValid()) {
        QString fileName = data(indexes.first(), Qt::DisplayRole).toString();
        qDebug() << fileName;
        stream << fileName;
    }

    mimeData->setData("application/octet-stream", encodedData);
    return mimeData;
}

bool ExplorerModel::canDropMimeData(const QMimeData *data, Qt::DropAction action, int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parent)
{
    Q_UNUSED(action);
    Q_UNUSED(row);
    Q_UNUSED(parent);

    if (!data->hasFormat("application/octet-stream")) {
        return false;
    }

    if (column > 0) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

bool ExplorerModel::dropMimeData(const QMimeData *data, Qt::DropAction action, int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parent)
{
    if (!canDropMimeData(data, action, row, column, parent)) {
        return false;
    }

    if (action == Qt::IgnoreAction) {
        return true;
    }

    int beginRow;

    if (row != -1) {
        beginRow = row;
    } else if (parent.isValid()) {
        beginRow = parent.row();
    } else {
        beginRow = rowCount(QModelIndex());
    }

    QByteArray encodedData = data->data("application/octet-stream");
    QDataStream stream(&encodedData, QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    QString fileName;

    while (!stream.atEnd()) {
        stream >> fileName;
    }

    //removeRow(row, parent);
    insertRow(beginRow, parent);
    QModelIndex idx = index(beginRow, 0, QModelIndex());
    qDebug() << "Filename: " << fileName;
    setData(idx, fileName, Qt::UserRole);
    return true;
}
```

It does not copy or move items. Any ideas how to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to drag and drop a file containing only alphanumerical tokens (no spaces, no punctuations)?

Comment: @m7913d

Hello! I have tried it, but it still does not work.